# ToastData missing in Toastr

Tags: angular, toastr

I had ng2-Toasty implemented in my old Angular 5 application. I am trying to use ngx-toastr since ng2-Toasty doesnt support Aungular 8.

If you see below , the ngx-toastr doesnt seem to have an equivalent of ToastData

ng2-toasty

```
import { ToastyService, ToastyConfig, ToastOptions, ToastData } from 'ng2-toasty';
```

ngx-toastr

```
import { ToastrService, ToastConfig, ToastOptions} from 'ngx-toastr';
```

This is how it was used previously in code

```
var timeOutSeconds = message.timeOutSeconds ? message.timeOutSeconds * 1000 : 4000;

    let toastOptions: ToastOptions = {
      title: message.summary,
      msg: message.detail,
      timeout: isSticky ? 0 : timeOutSeconds
    };

    if (isSticky) {
          toastOptions.onAdd = (toast: ToastData) => this.stickyToasties.push(toast.id);

          toastOptions.onRemove = (toast: ToastData) => {
            let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toast.id, 0);

            if (index > -1) {
              this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
            }

            toast.onAdd = null;
            toast.onRemove = null;
          };
        }
```

Any idea what is the equivalent implementation using ngx-toastr

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: replacing ToastData as it doesnt seem to be there in ngx-toastr

Comment: yeah but what is toast data? what are you trying to do with it? e.g. When X happens,  I want Y to happen. ngx is simple in its implementation. You give the root module settings for how long toasts should appear, duplicates etc. then fire the toast events when you need through the injected service

Comment: ng2-toasty had a lot of messy part initialising the ToastOptions. ngx-toastr doesn't need such complex initialisation or options, you can simply use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is an interface that describes the methods you need;
`onShown`, `onHidden`, `onTap`, `onAction`.

```js
export interface ActiveToast {
  /** Your Toast ID. Use this to close it individually */
  toastId: number;
  /** the message of your toast. Stored to prevent duplicates */
  message: string;
  /** a reference to the component see portal.ts */
  portal: ComponentRef<any>;
  /** a reference to your toast */
  toastRef: ToastRef<any>;
  /** triggered when toast is active */
  onShown: Observable<any>;
  /** triggered when toast is destroyed */
  onHidden: Observable<any>;
  /** triggered on toast click */
  onTap: Observable<any>;
  /** available for your use in custom toast */
  onAction: Observable<any>;
}
```

**Example**

```js
const toaster = this.toastrService.success('OK');
toaster.onShown.subscribe(()=>{
   this.stickyToasties.push(toast.id);
});
toaster.onHidden.subscribe(()=>{
  let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toast.id, 0);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacement of ng2-toasty with ngx-toastr for this code can look something like this. Please try and let me know:

```
 var timeOutSeconds = message.timeOutSeconds ? message.timeOutSeconds * 1000 : 4000;

  this.toastrService.success(message.title, message.summary, {
    timeOut: isSticky ? 0: timeOutSeconds
  });

  if (isSticky) {

     this.ActiveToast.onShown.subscribe((toast)=>{
            this.stickyToasties.push(toast.id);
        })

     this.ActiveToast.onHidden.subscribe((toast)=>{

        let index = this.stickyToasties.indexOf(toast.id, 0);

        if (index > -1) {
          this.stickyToasties.splice(index, 1);
        }

        toast.onAdd = null;
        toast.onRemove = null;
     })

  }
```

Comment: I can see that you have replaced the toastoptions. Isnt there a toastoptions in ngx-toastr. I am passing toast options further in my code below  case MessageSeverity.info: this.toastrService.info(toastOptions); break;
      case MessageSeverity.success: this.toastrService.success(toastOptions); break;
      case MessageSeverity.error: this.toastrService.error(toastOptions); break
      case MessageSeverity.warn: this.toastrService.warning(toastOptions); break;

Comment: No, there are no options. What you can do alternatively is to save the title, message, time in variables and then pass them like:
case MessageSeverity.info: this.toastrService.info(title, msg, {timeout: time}); break; case MessageSeverity.success: this.toastrService.success(title, msg, {timeout: time}); break; case MessageSeverity.error: this.toastrService.error(title, msg, {timeout: time}); break case MessageSeverity.warn: this.toastrService.warning(title, msg, {timeout: time}); break;

Comment: You have mentioned the use of this.ActiveToast isnt that an interface. I have tried to use that in the import and injected in the constructor and getting eror Generic type 'ActiveToast<C>' requires 1 type argument(s). I have imported it this way import { ToastrService, ToastrConfig, ActiveToast, ToastData } from 'ngx-toastr';  and injected it this way constructor(storageManager: LocalStoreManager, private toastrService: ToastrService, private toastyConfig: ToastrConfig, private activeToast: ActiveToast)

Comment: Also could you explain what is toastData in your code. in my code toastdata was toast: ToastData. So your code is not replacing the funtionality of toastdata

Answer (score -1):

You simply have to call the following functions in order to show a toastr when you're using ngx-toastr

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('Hello Success!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }

  showError() {
    this.toastr.error('Hello Error!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }

  showInfo() {
    this.toastr.info('Hello Info!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }

  showWarning() {
    this.toastr.warning('Hello Warning!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }
}
```

This will also help you in understanding the exact implementation:
DEMO: https://ngx-toastr.netlify.com/

Comment: @Tom, please give a proper explanation to what you're trying to do here so that I could help you.

Comment: I am basically new to both ng2-toasty and ngx-toastr. As I can see ng2-toasty references library ToastData and I have shared the code above to show how ToastData is used in the code. I am basically trying to see how to get that part of the code replaced with ngx-toastr

Comment: I've posted another answer. Please try and let me know.